# Write to a range of variable size

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro that involves the user inputting some variables. As a result of this I need to be able to select (and autofill) a range of varying size. Below is the code I want to use to autofill this variable range. As you can see, I want to autofill the range A2:Axxx, where xxx = 1 + patientprofiles. The code below works if patientprofiles = 50, for example, but I don't want to have to edit the macro every time; I want the range to adjust itself based on the user inputs.

```
Dim patientprofiles As Integer

Worksheets("Inputs").Select
patientprofiles = Cells(2, "B").Value

Worksheets("Work").Activate
Cells(2, 1) = 101
Cells(3, 1) = 102

Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Work").Range("A2:A3")
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Work").Range("A2:A51")
SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
```

Comment: @ScottCraner: That is a valid answer. Why not post it as an answer ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I was being lazy.  Thanks for the push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method of the Range() object criterion is a string denoting the beginning and end cells separated by `:`.

We can concatenate strings using the `&`.  We start with the set items of the string, those that will not change: `"A2:A"` Then add to that the variable: `patientprofiles +1`.

The final string is `"A2:A" & patientprofiles +1`

So:

```
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Work").Range("A2:A51")
```

would be:

```
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Work").Range("A2:A" & patientprofiles +1)
```

Comment: ++ nicely explained :)

Comment: @sarcasm24 Glad to help.  Please remember to mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: Done! I have a follow up question though: how can I do the same thing if both the beginning and the end of the range need to be variable? For example, I want to write from Exxx to Eyyy, where xxx = patientprofiles + 2 and yyy = 2*patientprofiles + 2. I've tried the following: .Range(E & patientprofiles + 2:E & 2 * patientprofiles + 2) but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @sarcasm24 gain it comes down to concatenating with the `&` Each time you switch from set parameter text to vba and back you need to use `&`.  So `"A" & patientprofiles + 2 & ":A" & patientprofiles * 2`